# Metaschema specifying required attribute for all properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to customize a metaschema such that all properties are required to have an additional attribute, for example, how could I require that all properties specify a `"type"`?

Then this schema should fail:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

But this one should succeed:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "...",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, writing meta-schemas is not easy. It's being worked on, but there's no good solution yet.

You would have to make a copy of the meta-schema you want to extend and then add `"required": ["type"]`.

But, while we're here, maybe I can convince you not to do this. Making the `type` keyword required causes problems in some cases. Here are a few examples. https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/issues/172#issuecomment-124214534

## EDIT

After discussing this further, we found that this particular case doesn't have the problems we normally run into with extending meta-schemas because it doesn't need to be recursive. Here is an example of extending the draft-06 schema to include a new keyword called `custom` which is a boolean and is required only at the top level of a `properties` schema.

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#" },
    {
      "properties": {
        "properties": {
          "patternProperties": {
            ".*": {
              "properties": {
                "custom": { "type": "boolean" }
              },
              "required": ["custom"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's an example schema that conforms to this meta-schema.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "custom": true,
      "not": { "type": "string" }
    }
  }
}
```

The `custom` keyword is required for the "foo" schema, but not the `not` schema or the top level schema.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I was under the impression that I could use an `allOf` to include all of the criteria from the normal `draft-X` schema, and then add in a new requirement.  I understand that there are reasons not to have `type` be required, and we *may* not need that in our case, but there is a custom attribute that we do *definitely* need to be required for all properties and I was just using `type` as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy. It's a little difficult to explain (especially in a comment), but when you just use `allOf`, only the top level of the schema will include the new constraints. Any other schemas, such as the ones within `properties` will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations - they're quite helpful!  But, yikes.  That's brutal... and seems like largely a deal-breaker for many use cases.

Comment: This schema does not imply `type` check. Parameter `custom` can be of any type. To control type as well, you need to include `custom` as a property inside `patternProperties`, e.g.:
`{"allOf": [{"$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#"},{"properties": {"properties": {"patternProperties": {
            "^.*$": {
              "properties": {
                "custom": {
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "custom"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @ollamh Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it. It does, of course, check the type, it just does it at the wrong level.