# creating a more strict meta schema for jsonschema's it self

Tags: schema, jsonschema, extend

I want to validate a JSON Schema to see if the JSON Schema is valid. So I don't want to validate a standard JSON document against a schema.

I need a meta schema that is a bit more strict than [the current meta schema](http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema).

I would like to have a schema that

- only allows appropriate properties on a type

  - e.g. not `maxLength` on a int type
- adds custom required fields on a type.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160774/metaschema-specifying-required-attribute-for-all-properties) some insights are given by @JasonDesrosiers.

I was wondering if there is any update on the improvements and an example of how to extend the meta schema.

Comment: What you're asking is a complex task. You can certinly create a more restricted meta-schema, but it's tricky to achive. We (the core team) certinly haven't looked at creating such a meta-schema, and it's unlikely that we will in the near future. If you try and get stuck, feel free to ask questions, but it currently looks like you're asking "has anyone done this and where can I find it?" which is "off topic" for StackOverflow.

Comment: JSON Schema also has a super friendly Slack server. Feel free to join using the discussion link on the official site.

Comment: Right now the best example of extending a meta-schema is the hyper-schema meta-schema https://json-schema.org/draft-07/hyper-schema. All that is to add two additional keywords. In the next draft there are two new keywords (`$recursiveRef` and `$recursiveAnchor`) that aim to make creating and meta-schemas easier.

Comment: I come across people trying to create a stricter meta-schema from time to time. I've never seen anyone share a finished product tho.

Comment: @Relequestual, thanks for the feedback. I would have thought that it would be the first thing to do. Making a json schema that actually could validate json schema's. Since it is the hardest schema to validate i guess..  But i will take a look at the slack server and try to create it. I'll probably need some help but i will post my questions there...

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Frans There IS a JSON Schema that validates JSON Schemas. It's the meta-schema. You are wanting to add rules on how keywords can be used together. It's a nice idea, but you'd need more than just a schema to achieve this. Consider if someone creates an `allOf` which references multiple other schemas. You would have to check each of those schemas to see if they have conflicting conditions. In the case of `if/then/else`, you also may have MANY possible resulting combinations of schemas being applied to a single instance.

Comment: At a very simple level, you MAY be able to do what you want, but it's going to lead you into a false sense of security, because you cannot protect fully against what you want to avoid. The real question is WHY do you want to do this? What is the problem that lead you to feel this is the solution?